# How do I get values from this array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Very much new to PHP and completely stuck because of @attributes when trying to pick values out of an array. I have previously converted an xml file into a associative array.

```
print_r(array_keys($newArray));
```

Prints:

```
Array ( [0] => @attributes [1] => rate )
```

```
print_r ($newArray);
```

Prints:

```
Array ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [base] => GBP 
        [ts] => 1572881347 ) 
        [rate] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [@attributes] => Array (   
                    [code] => AED 
                    [rate] => 4.739532203531 
                    [live] => 0 
                ) 
            ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [@attributes] => Array ( 
                    [code] => AFN 
                    [rate] => 100.80144337913 
                    [live] => 0     
                ) 
            ) 
            [2] => Array ( 
                [@attributes] => Array ( 
                    [code] => ALL 
                    [rate] => 142.29721877018 
                    [live] => 0 
                ) 
            ) 
            [3] => Array ( 
                [@attributes] => Array ( 
                    [code] => AMD 
                    [rate] => 614.98298701028 
                    [live] => 0 
            )
        )
```

How would I specify and print the last value?

```
[3] => Array ( [@attributes] => Array ( [code] => AMD [rate] => 614.98298701028 [live] => 0.
```

With the goal to output something like: AMD, 614.98298701028, 0

Thanks

Comment: It would be just as easy to work with the original XML than mess around with the data.  If you want help to learn how, then try using SimpleXML and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Why does `@attributes` make it any more complicated? It's just a key in an associative array, nothing special about it. `$newarray['@attributes']['rate'][3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, if you'd want to look-up a currency in your array, you could use following recursive function:

```
$code = 'AMD'; // set the curncy you want to lookup
forex($code, $newArray); // invoke the recursive function
// output:
//code : AMD
//rate : 614.98298701028

function forex(string $code = '', array $arr = []): void
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && $key !== '@attributes') {
            forex($code, $value);
        } else {
            if (isset($value['code']) && $value['code'] == $code) {
                echo 'code : ' . $value['code'];
                echo '<br />';
                echo 'rate : ' . $value['rate'];
                echo '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/IDvS3)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your original array is something like this:

```
$a = array(
    '@attributes' => array(
        'base' => 'GBP',
        'ts' => 1572881347),
    'rate' => array(
        0 => array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'code' => 'AED',
                'rate' => 4.739532203531,
                'live' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        1 => array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'code' => 'AFN',
                'rate' => 100.80144337913,
                'live' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        2 => array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'code' => 'ALL',
                'rate' => 142.29721877018,
                'live' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        3 => array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'code' => 'AMD',
                'rate' => 614.98298701028,
                'live' => 0,
            ),
        )));
```

then you can get what you want with this:

```
$last_rate = sizeof($a['rate']) - 1;

foreach ($a['rate'][$last_rate]['@attributes'] as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value ";
}
```

Which will output:

```
AMD 614.98298701028 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array will always contain the array values under `rate`,  you can retrieve the last element of the `rate` array by using [`end($newArray['rate'])`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

To output a CSV style string you can simply use [`implode(', ', $last['@attributes'])`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or another desired method, such as [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), to display the values from the last element.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/FNuuZ

```
if ($last = end($newArray['rate'])) {
     echo implode(', ', $last['@attributes']);
}
```

Result:

```
AMD, 614.98298701028, 0
```